# Replacing NaN values with column mean value does not change pandas dataframe NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I've search this topic in several posts and I have tried all possible solutions that people give but even though still does not work for me.

Im trying to replace each NaN value from each column, with it's column mean value. In other words:

```
    A   B
 1: 2   3
 2: 2   1
 3: NaN 4

Column A mean = 1.3

    A   B
 1: 2   3
 2: 2   1
 3: 1.3 4
```

I've tried:

```
df.fillna(value=0, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

and works fine, but as soon as I tried:

```
df.fillna(value=df.mean(axis=1), inplace=True)
```

I don't get any changes at all, NaN value still there.

Here is the piece of code:

```
# Drop 'station' column
del final_df['station']
# Replace NaN with column mean value
final_df.fillna(value=final_df.mean(axis=1), inplace=True)
final_df.head()
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) by means per columns by means per columns (axis=0), which is default value, so should be omit:

```
df = df.fillna(value=df.mean())
print (df)
      A  B
1:  2.0  3
2:  2.0  1
3:  2.0  4
```

I think `inplace` is not good practice, check [this](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace) and [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529).

Comment: changing the code line to: df = df.fillna(df.mean()) worked. I was unaware about the incorrect use of 'inplace'. Anyway, thank you!!!